# Add "Return to nomination" link to nomination revision page

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, revisions-list, nominations

Any post revision page contains a link "Return to {post}" at the top of the page:

> [image: Return to Question]

But there is no such link in candidate nomination revision page, [e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15148025/revisions):

> [image: No return to nomination]

Without a link it's impossible to navigate back to the [nomination post](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4#post-15148025) if you came on the revision page via direct link.

Could we please add a link in that case too?