# Election: Questionnaire history is titled "Revisions to unknown"

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, revisions-list, window-title

On the [Mathematics election](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/9) page, there is a minor bug in that clicking on a candidate's questionnaire history from the drop-down box [it looks like "history" has a larger font size?] leads to a revision list where the browser tab description reads "Revisions to unknown - Mathematics Stack Exchange" instead of "Revisions to questionnaire": [Example](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4302277/revisions)

[image: screenshot of the bug]

Comment: Might be related to: [Vote-totals tooltip says moderator nominations are questions, on the Primary election-phase tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370958/348196)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? I don't see a header on that page at all - which is a problem in its own way but I don't see the text you're seeing - possibly because you're looking at your own nomination? Can you compare yours with other users' nomination history page?

Comment: @Catija I meant on the tab (not the header). See the name of the tab on https://i.stack.imgur.com/3z0mb.png (this is from another candidate's nomination).

Comment: Ah. These are my tabs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1d9R.png 

Comment: @Catija actually there's another bug, missing "Return to [post]" link which should be on top. I'll report when having time, if not reported yet.

Comment: Yeah, that's the header I mean is missing in my first comment @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 ;) I'll add it to the bug report for this when it gets assigned.

Comment: @Catija two bugs in one? That's a good deal. Thanks! :D

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 Three, even - the oddly-sized "history" link is weird, too.

Comment: @Catija Thanks, it also seems the "history" link is in a different font (Arial), not just a different font size as spotted [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34286/is-the-font-difference-of-history-of-the-answers-of-a-nominated-user-for-the-e).

Comment: @Catija whoa, so I see SE is also taking part in the [Singles' Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singles%27_Day)! :-P

Comment: I think the oddly-sized "history" link was also noted by [Wrzlprmft](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/255554/wrzlprmft) here: [The “history” link under nominations on election pages is dislocated and larger than the others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368457)

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 Seems to have been reported here: [Add "Return to nomination" link to nomination revision page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362118).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the report!

The fixes to the revision pages are live now. The "history" link alignment fix is Coming Soon™ - it's fixed in our [design library](https://stackoverflow.design), so we're just waiting on the new version of that to hit the Q&A production environment. I would expect it to land early next week.