# History page for Help Center articles is titled "Revisions to unknown"

Tags: bug, help-center, revisions-list, window-title

Similar to [Election: Questionnaire history is titled "Revisions to unknown"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371773/295232), the history page for the Help Center articles editable by moderators, for example [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), is still titled "Revisions to unknown":

[image]

Here's a [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/183227/revisions) for staff to reproduce.